# sqlite determine if index is used

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, indexing

1. How to understand if created `index` used when `select` query run?
2. Specific example for my task:

Index:

```
  events (page,notuniqueid,type,timestamp);
```

SQL statement:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM events 
  WHERE type = 'comment' AND TIMESTAMP > $time AND PAGE = '$page' 
  LIMIT 1
```

Will index be used at this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out how a query is executed, run it with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html):

```
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * from events WHERE type='comment' AND TIMESTAMP > $time AND PAGE = '$page' LIMIT 1
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE events USING INDEX MyLittleIndex (page=?)
```

In this case, only the first column of the index can be used because there is no lookup on the `notuniqueuid` column.

A better index (for this query) would be on `(page,comment,timestamp)`.

(See [The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).)

Comment: thanks. but I have other query that already use index at my question. Need I create one additional index for other queries like at the example?

Comment: Using only the `page` column for indexed lookups might be fast enough for you. Or not. You have to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've used `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` as @CL described, you might want to see exactly what indexes you have...

```
SELECT name, tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index'
```